# kubectl apply/create "unexcpected EOF"

Tags: eof, kubectl

My kubectl can't read files and returns 'error: unexpected EOF' every time.

```
kubectl apply -f service.yaml
> error: unexpected EOF
```

I use a realy simple service.yaml like this, also this keeps happening on every file i try to read with kubectl:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myapp
spec:
  selector:
    app: myapp
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8090
  type: NodePort
```

Also the same error on `kubectl create -f service.yaml` and on `cat service.yaml | kubectl apply -f -`

Have removed+installed/updated/reinstalled it over gcloud:

```
gcloud version
>Google Cloud SDK 219.0.1
>core 2018.09.28
>docker-credential-gcr 
>gsutil 4.34
>kubectl 2018.09.17
```

also

```
kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.7", GitCommit:"0c38c362511b20a098d7cd855f1314dad92c2780", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-08-20T10:09:03Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"9+", GitVersion:"v1.9.7-gke.6", GitCommit:"9b635efce81582e1da13b35a7aa539c0ccb32987", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-08-16T21:33:47Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3b4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

This may be not a bug in kubectl but on some other component in my system which is used by kubectl to read files. But i have no clue where to look for.

System Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, everything up to date

**UPDATE:**
I checkd again with a `-v8` option to debug

```
I1013 11:31:43.750810   17705 loader.go:357] Config loaded from file /home/arno/.kube/config
I1013 11:31:43.751750   17705 round_trippers.go:384] GET https://[clusterIP]/openapi/v2
I1013 11:31:43.751766   17705 round_trippers.go:391] Request Headers:
I1013 11:31:43.751772   17705 round_trippers.go:394]     Accept: application/com.github.proto-openapi.spec.v2@v1.0+protobuf
I1013 11:31:43.751778   17705 round_trippers.go:394]     User-Agent: kubectl/v1.10.7 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/0c38c36
I1013 11:31:44.653232   17705 round_trippers.go:409] Response Status: 404 Not Found in 901 milliseconds
I1013 11:31:44.653254   17705 round_trippers.go:412] Response Headers:
I1013 11:31:44.653263   17705 round_trippers.go:415]     Content-Type: application/json
I1013 11:31:44.653270   17705 round_trippers.go:415]     Content-Length: 524
I1013 11:31:44.653285   17705 round_trippers.go:415]     Date: Sat, 13 Oct 2018 09:31:44 GMT
I1013 11:31:44.653291   17705 round_trippers.go:415]     Audit-Id: e765ef72-8c26-4b67-9039-901efc147cba
I1013 11:31:44.654650   17705 request.go:874] Response Body: {
"paths": [
 "/apis",
 "/apis/",
 "/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io",
 "/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1",
 "/healthz",
 "/healthz/etcd",
 "/healthz/ping",
 "/healthz/poststarthook/generic-apiserver-start-informers",
 "/healthz/poststarthook/start-apiextensions-controllers",
 "/healthz/poststarthook/start-apiextensions-informers",
 "/metrics",
 "/swagger-2.0.0.json",
 "/swagger-2.0.0.pb-v1",
 "/swagger-2.0.0.pb-v1.gz",
 "/swagger.json",
 "/swaggerapi",
 "/version"
 ]
}
I1013 11:31:44.663105   17705 round_trippers.go:384] GET https://[clusterIP]/swagger-2.0.0.pb-v1
I1013 11:31:44.663130   17705 round_trippers.go:391] Request Headers:
I1013 11:31:44.663138   17705 round_trippers.go:394]     User-Agent: kubectl/v1.10.7 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/0c38c36
I1013 11:31:44.663144   17705 round_trippers.go:394]     Accept: application/json, */*
I1013 11:31:44.688907   17705 round_trippers.go:409] Response Status: 200 OK in 25 milliseconds
I1013 11:31:44.688928   17705 round_trippers.go:412] Response Headers:
I1013 11:31:44.688935   17705 round_trippers.go:415]     Date: Sat, 13 Oct 2018 09:31:44 GMT
I1013 11:31:44.688942   17705 round_trippers.go:415]     Etag: "629C2395D5FEDD5D2ED46FE7C691E126BE621789A85F507C44292E9B50E3285AEBBA55D242800C3C9B0A9258E64444CE3B55BD8E485788936DAE773C6548EA64"
I1013 11:31:44.688951   17705 round_trippers.go:415]     Last-Modified: Sun, 08 Jul 2018 16:39:40 GMT
I1013 11:31:44.688960   17705 round_trippers.go:415]     Vary: Accept-Encoding
I1013 11:31:44.688969   17705 round_trippers.go:415]     X-From-Cache: 1
I1013 11:31:44.688976   17705 round_trippers.go:415]     Accept-Ranges: bytes
I1013 11:31:44.688983   17705 round_trippers.go:415]     Content-Type: application/octet-stream
I1013 11:31:44.785113   17705 request.go:872] Response Body:
00000000  0a 03 32 2e 30 12 14 0a  0a 4b 75 62 65 72 6e 65  |..2.0....Kuberne|
00000010  74 65 73 12 06 76 31 2e  39 2e 37 42 d4 e0 5f 12  |tes..v1.9.7B.._.|
00000020  ca 02 0a 05 2f 61 70 69  2f 12 c0 02 12 bd 02 0a  |..../api/.......|
00000030  04 63 6f 72 65 1a 1a 67  65 74 20 61 76 61 69 6c  |.core..get avail|
00000040  61 62 6c 65 20 41 50 49  20 76 65 72 73 69 6f 6e  |able API version|
00000050  73 2a 12 67 65 74 43 6f  72 65 41 50 49 56 65 72  |s*.getCoreAPIVer|
00000060  73 69 6f 6e 73 32 10 61  70 70 6c 69 63 61 74 69  |sions2.applicati|
00000070  6f 6e 2f 6a 73 6f 6e 32  10 61 70 70 6c 69 63 61  |on/json2.applica|
00000080  74 69 6f 6e 2f 79 61 6d  6c 32 23 61 70 70 6c 69  |tion/yaml2#appli|
00000090  63 61 74 69 6f 6e 2f 76  6e 64 2e 6b 75 62 65 72  |cation/vnd.kuber|
000000a0  6e 65 74 65 73 2e 70 72  6f 74 6f 62 75 66 3a 10  |netes.protobuf:.|
000000b0  61 70 70 6c 69 63 61 74  69 6f 6e 2f 6a 73 6f 6e  |application/json|
000000c0  3a 10 61 70 70 6c 69 63  61 74 69 6f 6e 2f 79 61  |:.application/y [truncated 10504225 chars]
F1013 11:31:44.806007   17705 helpers.go:119] error: unexpected EOF
```

Comment: Have you checked your cluster running and health status of system Pods: `kubectl cluster-info`, `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o wide` ?

Comment: `kubectl cluster-info`and `get pods` works fine

Comment: Do you have all cluster runtime components up and heatlhy under `kube-system` namespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part with the failed response was indicating a version mismatch:

```
I1013 11:31:43.751750   17705 round_trippers.go:384] GET https://[clusterIP]/openapi/v2
I1013 11:31:43.751766   17705 round_trippers.go:391] Request Headers:
I1013 11:31:43.751772   17705 round_trippers.go:394]     Accept: application/com.github.proto-openapi.spec.v2@v1.0+protobuf
I1013 11:31:43.751778   17705 round_trippers.go:394]     User-Agent: kubectl/v1.10.7 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/0c38c36
I1013 11:31:44.653232   17705 round_trippers.go:409] Response Status: 404 Not Found in 901 milliseconds
```

The google kubernetes cluster was on an older version, something like `1.9.x` and my gcloud kubectl was `1.10.7`. After updating the Cluster it works again.